# How to check if a radiobutton is selected in GTK

Tags: c, radio-button, gtk

I am trying to create a GUI in GTK using C. I want to have radio buttons but I don't know how to determine which one is selected.

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static gboolean close_application( GtkWidget *widget,
                                   GdkEvent  *event,
                                   gpointer   data )
{
  gtk_main_quit ();
  return FALSE;
}

static void btn_selected()
{
    //pop-up message; left empty for now   
}

int main( int   argc,
          char *argv[] )
{
    GtkWidget *window = NULL;
    GtkWidget *box1;
    GtkWidget *box2;
    GtkWidget *button;
    GtkWidget *separator;
    GSList *group;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);    

    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    g_signal_connect (window, "delete-event",
              G_CALLBACK (close_application),
                      NULL);

    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "radio buttons");
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 0);

    box1 = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 0);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box1);
    gtk_widget_show (box1);

    box2 = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 10);
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (box2), 10);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box1), box2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show (box2);

    button = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label (NULL, "button1");
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box2), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show (button);

    group = gtk_radio_button_get_group (GTK_RADIO_BUTTON (button));
    button = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label (group, "button2");
    gtk_toggle_button_set_active (GTK_TOGGLE_BUTTON (button), TRUE);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box2), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show (button);

    button = gtk_radio_button_new_with_label_from_widget (GTK_RADIO_BUTTON (button),
                                                      "button3");
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box2), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show (button);

    separator = gtk_hseparator_new ();
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box1), separator, FALSE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show (separator);

    box2 = gtk_vbox_new (FALSE, 10);
    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (box2), 10);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box1), box2, FALSE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show (box2);

    button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("close");
    g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked",
                              G_CALLBACK (close_application),
                              window);
    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX (box2), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_set_can_default (button, TRUE);
    gtk_widget_grab_default (button);
    gtk_widget_show (button);

    //This button will call the btn_selected method when clicked
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("selected");
    g_signal_connect(button,"clicked",G_CALLBACK (btn_selected),NULL);
    gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX(box2),button,TRUE,TRUE,0);
    gtk_widget_show(button);

    gtk_widget_show (window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

The GUI comes up without any errors, I just don't know to check which radio button was selected so I can perform an action. Since all the buttons are named button I don't know how to check for a specific one.I got this code from a gtk tutorial online.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GtkRadioButton is descended from GtkToggleButton so you can connect to the 'toggled' signal or use the 'active' property to the the state of the button.